# PEM certificate gives "wrong tag" or "header too long" errors

Tags: node.js, ssl, pem

I try to use PEM certificate chain , it looks like this:

```
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
...
...
...
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
...
...
...
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
...
...
...
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

When I run it inside the node.js like this:

```
tls.createSecureContext({
  rejectUnauthorized: false,
  pfx: fs.readFileSync('cert.pem'),
})
```

I got errors like "wrong tag" or "header too long" if file is in UTF8 or UTF8-BOM, correspondly. What's probably wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I was using an outdated certificate that caused me "header too long". Changed to the current one and started working!